# select the value to populate html.dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two classes as follows

```
public class ODCTE_Major
{
    public int    ODCTE_MajorId { get; set; }
    public string OfficialMajorName      { get; set; }
    public string MajorCode { get; set; }

    ... More unrelated code ....
}
```

AND

```
public class CareerMajor
{
    ...lots of unrealted code to this question left out

    public int ODCTE_MajorId { get; set; }
    public virtual ODCTE_Major ODCTE_Major { get; set; }


}
```

I added a controller with CRUD methods and in the create.cshtml there is this line

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ODCTE_MajorId", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ODCTE_MajorId)
</div>
```

The select list populates it with the OfficialMajorName from ODCTE_Major. I need the select list to populate with the MajorCode or a value that looks like MajorCode - OfficialMajorName.

Could someone provide assistance for how this is done, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to ODCTE_Major:

```
public string MajorDisplayName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", MajorCode, OfficialMajorName); }
}
```

This is just a read only property used to create the display text in the format you want the menu to use.

Then in CareerMajor, add:

```
public IEnumerable<ODCTE_Major> Majors{ set; get; } // Thank you Shyju!
```

This will give you a place in your view model to pass the list of Majors you want in your menu to the view.

Then in your action method when you're creating a CareerMajor view model to send to the view, populate the new IEnumberable with the ODCTE_Major entities you'd like displayed in your menu.

On the view page:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ODCTE_MajorId, new SelectList(Model.Majors, "ODCTE_MajorId", "MajorDisplayName", Model.ODCTE_MajorId), "Select One")
```

This creates a SelectList to populate the drop down with.  The SelectList constructor is saying use ODCTE_MajorId as the value for a SelectListItem in the menu, and to use MajorDisplayName as the text to actually display in the menu.  It sets the selected value, if there is one, and adds a null item with the text "Select One" to the top of the menu.  Feel free to take that final argument out if you don't want the null text.

Comment: This worked. I looked at it again and couldn't understand why I didn't see this at first. Long day... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have your ViewModel hold a `Collection` property to represent all available Majors (for poulating the Dropdown)

```
public class CareerMajor
{  
  //other proiperties
   public int ODCTE_MajorId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<ODCTE_Major> Majors{ set; get; }
}
```

And in your `GET` Action, fill it and send it to your strongly typed view

```
pubilc ACtionResult Create()
{
  var viewModel=new CareerMajor();
  viewModel.Majors=db.GetllAllMajors();  // getting a list of ODCTE_Major objects
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

and in the View, use the `DropDownListFor` HTML Helper method.

```
@model CareerMajor
@Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ODCTE_MajorId, 
        new SelectList(Model.Majors,"ODCTE_MajorId ","MajorCode"),"select one..")
  //other elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action:

```
ViewBag.ODCTE_MajorId = new SelectList(availableMajors, "ODCTE_MajorId", "MajorCode");
```

*second and third parameters are the names of the value and text fields respectively

Then in your view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ODCTE_MajorId", String.Empty)
```

where `availableMajors` is an IEnumerable that contains the majors you want to list.