# I want to populate text box with dropdown selection with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table `compte` with

- id
- login
- mail
- mobile

I want to display the login with a dropdown list and when the user selects login the mobile and the email should be displayed automatically in 2 text boxes based on his selection.

Can someone help or give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are not expecting us to write the code from scratch , but looking for some steps how to achieve this

**1)**  Get All Login Column values from your Data Access layer (table/Cache) and [Show that in a DropDown.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11677024/40521)

**2)** Listen to the change event of the Dropdown , in javascript. When the change event occurs, get the selected Item's value and Make an Ajax call to another `Action` method and pass the selected value of the Dropdown as a parameter of this method .The Action method should get the corresponding record from your table for this purticular login and return the result in `JSON` format to the client.

**3)** in the call back of your ajax method, Read the `JSON` and Set the value of the Text boxes.

```
$(function(){
    $("#LoginDropDown").change(function(){
      var val=$(this).val();

       $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetDetails","Home")/"+val,function(data){
            if(data.Status=="Success")
            {
              $("#txtMail").val(data.Mail);
              $("#txtMobile").val(data.Mobile);
            }    
        });    
    });      
});
```

Assuming your Action method Returns a JSON in this format.

```
{
    "Status": "Success",
    "Mail": "you@outlook.com",
    "Mobile": "242342344"
}
```

Comment: thankx i did the same thing but it didn't work for me this is ma action  to get the mobile for example   public ActionResult Mobile( string dd1 )
     {
      
        compte compte = db.compte.Single(c => c.login == dd1);

        return Json(compte.mobile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

Comment: @NasnousaBh: If you have an error, you should post that as a question with ONLY relevant details.

Comment: ok thank you but i just want to know how can i get the selected value of the dropdownlist from the view to use it in my controller action

Comment: @NasnousaBh: that is already in my answer( sample code). on the Change event of the Dropdown, get the value by calling the `val()` method.

Comment: this is my contrller action: return Json(compte.mobile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    public ActionResult Index2()

    {
        var compteList = new SelectList(db.compte.ToList(), "id_compte", "login");

        ViewData["comptes"] = compteList;
        return View("Index2");
    }