# ASP.NET MVC 5 get 3 models data in 1 view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do small application in mvc 5. In this I have 3 models say Organisation model, Product model and Package model.

Organisation model:

```
namespace Own.Models
{
  public class OrganisationViewModel
  {
    [Key]
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Organisation name")]
    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter organisation address")]
    public string OrganisationAddress { get; set; }
```

Package Model:

```
namespace Own.Models
{
  public class PackageViewModel
  {
    [Key]
    public int PackageID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter packagename")]
    public string Packagename { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter packagedescription")]
    public string PackageDescription { get; set; }
```

Product Model:

```
namespace Own.Models
{
  public class ProductViewModel
  {
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Product Description")]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
```

Now, I need to create another model named Submission model. Here in this Submission view I want the three dropdown lists for Organisation, Product and Package. If I select Organisation dropdown by selecting item in that dropdown it should display Organisation ID, Organisation Name and Organisation Address (just it should display details, read only).

Similarly for Package and Product also it should display all details and after displaying full details in one view at bottom there should be button to save the details. Here I am not using any database. Only some static data. How to display all 3 models data in that final model view? and how to get that read only data when selecting the drop down.

Comment: Where are you getting the data for Organisation, Product and Package ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You basically need to [render the dropdown in your view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300916/dropdownlist-from-ienumerable/34301135#34301135), and [when an item is selected, make an ajax call and pass the id to get the details and show that in the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759750/i-want-to-populate-text-box-with-dropdown-selection-with-jquery). Which part are you having trouble with  ? Show us your specific issue.

Comment: i would suggest you to create a WireframeModel (ViewModel) for you view and reference the three object in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create anonamous type to concat fields

```
 obj  =db.Org
.Where(...)
.ToList()
.Select(s => new 
 { ID=s.ID,
   Description = string.Format("{0}-- £{1}", s.Name,s.Description) 
 });

 Viewbag.OrgDdl=new SelectList(obj,"ID","Description");
```

In you view, you can use it like this

```
             @Html.DropDownListFor(m1 => m1.ID, ViewBag.OrgDdl as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this issue is creating a `View Model` consisting three mentioned objects as properties. Something like:

```
public class MyNewViewModel
{
  public OrganisationViewModel MyOrganisation { get; set; }
  public PackageViewModel MyPackage { get; set; }
  public ProductViewModel MyProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could populate your properties inside `MyNewViewModel` constructor at first or you can populte them seperatly during any action or ajax callback. So you will have your whole related data on view.